# Find the maximum number of all-one rows

Tags: mathematics, optimization

We've got an $N \times M$ matrix whose elements are either zero or one. For example:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

You are allowed to toggle the values of any given column in the matrix. If you toggle a column, 0s become 1 and 1s become 0 in it. e.g. toggling the second  column will result in:

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

As you can see, the first row became all ones. What's the maximum number of rows that can become all ones after applying $K$ number of toggles? You can toggle a column multiple times and you are not allowed to perform the toggle less than $K$ times. Constraints: $1 \leq N \leq 50 $ and $1 \leq M \leq 20 $

Comment: Are we starting with a general $N\times M$ matrix, so that the final answer could depend on $N$, $M$, and $K$? (I.e. we're not starting from the $5\times5$ matrix you drew - that's just an example?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes that's just an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> however many times the most common row with at most $K$ 0s and the same parity as $K$ 0s in it appears.

Proof:

> First, note that toggling a column does not change whether two rows are identical.
>  Thus, if two rows end up with all 1s, they must have been identical to begin with.
>  Then the most common row which can be made into all 1s is the maximal choice.
>  Any row with at most $K$ 0s can be toggled into the all 1s row with at most $K$ steps.
>  Thus, the most common row with at most $K$ 0s is the best choice, and however many times that row appears is the most all-1 rows we can end up with.
>  The number of 0s in the most common row must also have the same parity as $K$, as we alter the parity with each toggle.